# select columns different tables Django

Tags: sql, django, join

I want to do this query:

```
SELECT scf_cliente.nombre, scf_cotizacion.fecha FROM scf.scf_cliente join scf.scf_cotizacion on scf.scf_cliente.id = scf.scf_cotizacion.cliente_identificacion_id
```

in Django, I tried with filters but only returns data from a single table, in this case of just one model.

```
resultado = Cotizacion.objects.filter(cliente_identificacion_id = cliente).select_related()
```

Comment: It is totally doable using [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Comment: thanks, but would be more specific?